# ssh to avahi announced host failing due to 'unknown host' even if it's discovered

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, avahi

I have a raspberry announcing it's hostname with avahi-daemon for several services. However, even if I receive this at PCs over my network I cannot ssh it.

```
$ avahi-browse -at | grep -i ssh
+ wlp3s0 IPv4 raspi                SSH Remote Terminal  local
+ wlp3s0 IPv4 arch                 SSH Remote Terminal  local

$ ssh pi@raspi.local
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspi.local: Name or service not known

$ ssh pi@raspi
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspi: Name or service not known
```

I've tryed changing the `host` line at `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and some params at `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`

avahi-discover shows perfectly it's IPv4 and IPv6, but when I get my machine known hosts all I get is my own machine

```
$ getent hosts 
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost arch
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost arch
```

I've also tryed setting the IP to static at `/etc/network/interfaces` or trying to announce the hostname from dhclient.conf setting `send host-name = "raspberry.pi";` with the same luck.

Also there's no iptables service running or any other firewall.

Comment: Is it running Debian, Raspbian, Arch...? All of those six commands should echo Raspberry's hostname: `uname -n`, `hostname -a`, `hostname -s`, `hostname -d`, `hostname -f`, `hostname`, do they?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to add avahi to hostname resolution. Instructions for ArchLinux (which I suppose given that your machine's name seems to be arch) are available here : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Avahi#Hostname_resolution.

Comment: I've tryed it. I configured it and rebooted. It doesn't have a service or somewhere where I can reload `nnswitch.conf`?